# Linked Server vs. Ad Hoc (OpenRowset / OpenDatasource) Distributed Queries

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, distributed-transactions, openrowset

I have an application which needs to grab data from different clients' databases that reside at the client's location. So alongside their normal details such as company name, address etc, I also store the name of their DB server and the name of the database I need to interrogate.

The number of clients is currently zero. However, I expect this to grow to to around 200+ in a year's time.

I am a bit confused with which option to go with to run distributed queries:

> 1. Creating linked servers for every single client (up to 200+!)
> 2. Using an OpenDataSource() or OpenRowset() ad-hoc query within an SP that feeds in the DB server and DB name dynamically from the client
>      account table

Option 2 sounds the easiest to manage because if a client was to move their server or whatever, they just need to update their details in their account once and everything *should* work correctly.

But the reason I'm confused is because of this statement on Microsoft's site:

> OPENDATASOURCE should be used only to reference OLE DB data sources
>   that are accessed infrequently. For any data sources that will be
>   accessed more than several times, define a linked server.

The external DBs will get accessed quite frequently, with the majority of transactions being `SELECT` statements.

I'm also unsure to the security implications and which option is more tight for security. Does anyone have experience in this area and could give me some tips please?

Comment: Performance over linked servers is likely to bad due their inability to use statistics. Security will also be a concern. It sounds like this data should be transferred at the app layer if possible.

Comment: @JamesAnderson could you expand a bit more on the better solution of transferring data at the app layer? I didn't quite understand what that meant.

Comment: I believe Linked Servers can use statistics if you have the correct permissions. I would be the db_owner

Comment: yes that is correct but then the security hole is about as bad as it can be

Comment: @JamesAnderson so what other option is there to getting at data which resides on a customer's server? I could copy across the data from their server and then perform queries, but I'd still need a linked server connection to get at it. Would this be safer/better/scalable option?